# Required URI template variable 'userId' for method parameter type Integer is not present]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

getting the below exception
2023-10-10 16:15:56.383  WARN 31748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'userId' for method parameter type Integer is not present]

trying to create a delete api in springboot

Comment: Well the message/error is pretty clear.